# When evolving Pokemon, how is the evolved CP calculated?

Tags: pokemon-go

If I have two of the same Pokemon but with different CP but the same progress on their CP bars and I decide to evolve both, do they both receive the same CP boost directly from the evolution or does it vary by it's original CP?

Comment: My question is about CP boost upon evolution depending on original CP as opposed to candy powerup or CP potential pre and post.

Comment: I'm sorry but can you explain drawing parallels between my question and the linked one of where the overlap is? I am not addressing that answers are not helpful but the fact that the question is not what I am asking.

Here is _further_ clarification of the scenario: If I have 2 Rattatas both with 50% on the CP bar but one with 20 CP and the other with 30 CP and evolve both, will their resulting CPs have 10 CP difference as they were pre-evolution or not? If not, how is evolved CP calculated?

Comment: Your literally asking "does the pre-evolution CP effect the post-evolution CP", which is practically identical to "should I upgrade CP now, or wait untill I evolve the Pokemon",

Comment: The only part that does not immediately appear as an **obvious** duplicate is where you ask how the CP is determined. Ultimately, a good answer to the first part of the question would answer the later. If it was not so heavily related, we would close you question as "too broad" for asking 2 seperate questions.

Comment: No because I do not plan to upgrade any pokemon, I just intend to keep higher CP pokemon. If evolution CP boost is random there is a chance that evolving a lower CP pokemon will result in a higher CP than evolving the higher CP one and therefore allowing me to keep a higher CP original.

Comment: My question of asking how CP is determined is precisely the entire question, I have asked no two questions. I have simply received mass of misunderstanding and labelling on the question as to what people think I'm asking with assumptions like the one that you made about me wanting to upgrade CP with candies when it is irrelevant. Maybe people see the word 'boost' and immediately think 'upgrade' but the entire premise is me asking how the CP boost upon evolution is calculated and whether it is dependent on original CP.

Comment: Ultimately, at least 5 different people have had this "misunderstanding". Perhaps you should look at restructuring your question? There is a lot of reference to the CPs before and after evolution. Typically, I try to fix these myself, but it is such a mess that I am not sure how. Simplify the question. Just adding more examples to it does not help your case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42419/discussion-between-shiri-and-timelord64).

Comment: This is not dupe. Questions are different yet answers are same. This doesn't make the answer dupe.

Comment: This is a perfectly legit question & I've the same question. As my trainer level becomes higher, I'm encountering more high CP original Pokemon. I've no plan to power up any pokemon before evolving. If a high pre-evolution CP means a high post-evolution CP, I'm willing to wait to encounter a maxed out pre-evolution pokemon before I evolve it. If that's not the case, I can already evolve one of the low CP pokemon. So this is not at all a question similar to "Should I evolve first or power up first?"

Answer (score 2):

Yes. See the circular Combat Power bar behind your Pokemon's model? It stays the same percentage filled on evolution.

Answer (score 0):

The max CP of a Pokemon depends on weight and height I think. In your example of the Rattata's with the 50% CP bar and a difference of 10 in CP, one Rattata is probably bigger.

If you evolve or power up the Pokemon it seems to go up with an x-percentage of the max CP of that level Pokemon. (Based on the fact that costs for powering up are same before and after evolution)

So if you evolve both, their CP level will probably show the same increase in percentages. I don't think it will be easy to figure out the exact formula. Since height and weigth seem to determine the max CP level. Not sure about this theory though, but that's what I make out of it after reading a lot and seen examples.

If your CP bar is full and maxed out for your Rattata, it will also be full and maxed out on your Raticate after evolving.

So basically if you want to reach the highest CP possible for a certain kind of Pokemon, you need to find the fattest one out there. And then you can evolve and power it up to the max

Answer (score 0):

Phoenix is totally wrong.  CP is all over the map and isn't determined by weight or height or anything logical.  Still a mystery.

I currently have 4 Pidgey's I'm experimenting with.  The lightest and shortest Pidgey is the second highest CP.  Also the highest CP Pidgey isn't the highest Hitpoints, which is important for battling.  Sure the highest CP Pidgey is the heaviest and the tallest, but CP isn't all that goes into battling.  They have to be able to take the hits too so Hitpoints are important.  None of these Pidgey's have been powered up at all.  Given these 5 Pidgey's, I feel like the one to hold onto, without factoring in attack moves which are important too, would be the Pidgey with 191cp or 174cp.  I could power each of these up to 195cp and they would each have a lot more Hitpoints then the current 195cp Pidgey.

## 1 174cp  39 Hitpoints  1.74kg  .27m height,

## 2 186cp  41 Hitpoints 1.24kg  .27m height,

## 3 189cp  37 Hitpoints 1.31kg  .27m height,

## 4 191cp  43 Hitpoints 1.09kg  .24m height,

## 5 195cp  40 Hitpoints 2.22kg  .33m height